# Struts 2 redirect external URL with parameters

Tags: java, post, redirect, parameters, struts2

I want to make a POST HTTP request from a struts2 action to an external URL and send parameters in the request.

I have read that it can be done in this way: [External django redirect with POST parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345892/external-django-redirect-with-post-parameters) but I was wondering if it can be done in a different way, let's say, directly from the action and not throgh a JSP.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you're actually trying to do.

If you're trying to make a request from your action to another site, then do something with the response and return data to the user *without the user knowing the external site was accessed*, then you'd need to use something like Apache's HttpClient. That can be done anywhere, bt obviously doesn't belong in a JSP as you state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The external application will process the request and it will display a form to the user (user interaction is needed) so the URL of this external Web will be displayed.

Comment: Then you'd need to POST an actual form, although it can be created as hidden and submitted via JavaScript (as suggested on the other page). You can't do a sendRedirect as a POST AFAIK.