# Django POST to other view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have the following form that lives on the site root at `/`

```
<form action='/play/' method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.player_name }}
    <input id='play' type='submit' value='Play'>
</form>
```

then I have the view that validates this form:

```
def login(request):    
    context = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/play/')
        else:
            context.update(dict(form=form))
    else:
        context.update(dict(form=LoginForm(initial={'player_name':'Please tell us your name'})))

    return render_to_response('login.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And the actual play view:

```
def play(request):

    p1 = briscola.Player(request.POST['player_name'])
```

The problem is that of course the redirect looses the `POST` data. But why doesn't it `POST` directly to the play view by itself when the `form.is_valid`?

Comment: The easiest way is to store `player_name` at `request.session`. But I`d rather combine validation and actual play at the same view.

Comment: There's also another problem I just spotted that the first time the validation works but at the second attempt I'm able to submit an empty form and validation doesn't kick in

Comment: It's difficult to say something about validation problem without seeing form.

Comment: Look at this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345892/external-django-redirect-with-post-parameters

Comment: how did you solve this problem?